# Lubuntu desktop messed up

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

My lubuntu desktop is messed up and I don't know how to fix it. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the image on the left side there is a lot of panels and the indicator-multiload is too small.

Comment: What did you do before this happened?

Comment: It does not look like Lubuntu. How did you tweak the desktop environment?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Trying to fix the indicator-multiload widget press create new panel and that's the gray bars that are left that I can remove them, what I can not enlarge is the indicator-multiload widget

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact panel problem before (with the one on the left side). The problem is the size of the panel and the background for the panel.

You should be able to right-click that panel (it's only one... entity... for lack of a better word) and delete the panel as you would normally in LXDE.

As for the top panel, you could solve that by increasing the size of that panel by right-clicking and editing that as well.